# Mocking classes that created with app()->make

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have this code in my __construrct:

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->dbUserService = app()->make('DBUserService');
}
```

Now, when i'm unit testing i know that i can mock Guard and pass it's mock to $auth, but how can i mock `dbUserService` ? it's instantiated trough the IoC container.

Comment: Try `app()->bind('DBUserService', $DBUserServiceMock)`

Comment: Can you elaborate please? How exactly will this look inside a test case?

Comment: Sorry it's `instance()` not `bind()`. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `instance()` method of the IoC container to mock any class instanciated with `make()`:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(); // doesn't really matter from where you get the mock
// ...
$this->app->instance('DBUserService', $mock);
```

Answer (score 5):

In case of you need to mock an instance with contextual binding, for example:

```
app()->make(MyClass::class, ['id' => 10]);
```

You can use `bind` instead of `instance`:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(MyClass::class, function($mock) {
   $mock->shouldReceive('yourMethod')->once();
})

$this->app->bind(MyClass::class, function() use($mock) {
   return $mock;
});
```